# What’s the easiest way to access local websites from a Parallels / VMWare Fusion virtual Windows machine?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine

1. Develop a Rails app on your Mac.
2. Have a virtual Windows box using Parallels (on the same computer).
3. Want to test it in IE…
4. …without deploying it to staging
5. …or attempting to run your Rails environment within Windows

Is there any way to conveniently access port 3000 on my Mac from within Windows?

Comment: Doesn't the VM have an IP address on the local network?

Comment: @cHao Did I imply otherwise? How does that solve my problem?

Comment: `http://your.ip.addr.ess:3000`?  Hosts file?  If the VM is on the local network, it can talk to the host as if they were two separate machines.  All you need is for the VM to be able to resolve the host's name, and only then if the server is using name-based virtual hosting, which for a Rails server is kinda doubtful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should be pretty straight forward (for non-subdomained Rails apps). It definitely gets more complicated with subdomains.

#### Non-Subdomained App

1. From your Mac terminal:

   `ifconfig -a`
2. Copy the assigned IP address (e.g., 192.168.1.100)
3. Switch to Parallels, open IE and enter the IP address in the address bar. Don't forget to add the protocol and port number of the running Rails app. For example:

   `http://192.168.1.100:3000`
4. Voilà! Rails app.

#### Subdomained App

You should probably already be using something like `lvh.me` to ease the burden of creating subdomained applications locally (see [ASCIICasts 221: Subdomains in Rails 3](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)). It doesn't seem to be so straight-forward on Windows though.

1. Edit the Windows `hosts` file. It should be located somewhere like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`
2. Assuming your IP address is the same as above, add a line that looks similar to this, and save:

   `192.168.1.100   lvh.me sub1.lvh.me sub2.lvh.me ... subN.lvh.me`

   Where sub1, sub2, ..., subN are the subdomains that you want to access from IE.

You should now be able to access `http://sub1.lvh.me:3000` from IE.

#### A Final Note

I was getting pretty tired of looking up my DHCP allocated IP address every time, so I created a new Network location in OS X called Home that uses DHCP with a manually assigned IP address. That way, I can at least save some time when I'm working from home. Just remember to switch locations when you join a different network. YMMV :)

Comment: With a rails 4 app, on mac osx 10.9.1, the app is touched but the first asset loaded remains frozen… The app never ends to try to load (on the assets site). Quite stuck.

Comment: Be sure to use the full URL including the protocol (http://) and port (3000), otherwise it won't work. Otherwise, excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just some extra information, because I always forget this and I am assuming others might find it useful.

The default IP of the host (when I created with v8, and upgraded to 9) is below.  Maybe it's changed, but worth a "ping" first to see if it works.

```
10.211.55.22
```

The interface parallels uses is hidden from the network settings dialog.  Enable it by following these steps (works as of v9.)  Thanks to [Roger Johansson](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201209/ip_address-independent_access_to_mac_virtual_hosts_from_parallels_virtual_machines/) for the steps, which I no longer remembered.

- Ensure you are using Shared Networking
- Open `Preferences` from the `Parallels Desktop` main menu (not the VM's menu)
- Go to `Advanced` => `Network: [Change Settings]`
- Click "Show in system preferences"

To get the IP

- Open the "Network Preferences" panel
- You should see an entry now for `Para... #0`, the name will be cut off
- Click on it and you will see the IP assigned.  You can also change it (*i've never tried*)

[image: Parallels Shared Networking Interface Configuration on OS-X]

Answer (score 2):

nobody mentioned about port forwarding . so if for example you are using in MAC   http://localhost:5000/ **by default this port not able to use in Windows (with Parallels)**,   for Parallels you need to setup port forwarding. see below how to make it

List item

1. launch parallels
2. ping you IP in mac

> ifconfig | grep net

[image]

3. keep in mind this ip
4. then open network settings in parallels

looks it like this:
[image]

5. add port forwarding rules:

> for example incoming port 5000, destination port can be also 5000 (or different for example 8000), ip
>   addres:10.211.55.2